# Algebraic topology question (Qual)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am having trouble with a QR problem.  I would appreciate some help. Construct a connected $CW$-complex $X$ with $H_0(X, \mathbb{Z}) =
\mathbb{Z}, H_1(X, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_2(X, \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}
\times \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: What does QR mean? (I have upvoted your question, by the way)

Comment: I meant qualifying exam problem.  I thought that was abbreviated QR (Qualifying Review?).

Comment: Maybe, but what's  the advantage of using an acronym ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you first find a connected space with $$H_1(X,Z) = \mathbb{Z}_{10}$$ and $$H_2 = 0$$

How about a connected space with $$H_1 = \mathbb{Z}$$ and $$H_2 = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$$

Then maybe you can find a way to combine these spaces?

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Make use of the Kunneth formula for two spaces where one of them has trivial $n$th-degree homology.

Comment: This "hint" is much too vague . In particular why introduce an irrelevant (and non-quantified)   $n$ ? The purpose of this site is to help people, not confuse them.

Comment: Disagree. In fact, a good hint would simply be *"use Kunneth formula"*... I just decided to add an extra hint, which is *definitely* not irrelevant.